# OctoberCMS Publisher role permissions seem strange to me

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I have an admin superuser created and I am logged in. I can create roles and users, but I cannot edit the permissions of the Developer and Publisher roles that have already been created. All the checkboxes are disabled. Docs say these are not editable.

But the publisher role does not have access to publish or edit anything in the CMS. That can't be right can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Normal, you can check code base those 2 ROLES are default `System Role` **you can not edit them**.

https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/modules/backend/models/UserRole.php#L14

To make role editable you can add your own new role and assign them to users.

In your case you can just duplicate that `Publisher` role and use it like `Custom_Publisher` and now you can assign it rights you wanted.

> Publisher can not edit anything He can just Publish `Post`, **Actually it depends on plugin which `rights` they respect for publishing.**

You can see for `CMS , Static Page` there seems **no publishing thing**, **but for `Post` plugin you see there is `You can Publish Post`** so it can be useful there.

**That is why `System Roles [developer, publisher]` are not editable, so we don't mess its permissions, and make official supported `plugins/packages [CMS, Media, Blog Post, Static Pages ..etc.. ]` useless as they depend on that permissions.**

> **To Overcome that** you can just `Duplicate Role and Modify it Rights` and assign them to users as per your need.

If you have any doubts please comment.